# NSTextView quote level

Tags: cocoa, webview, nstextview

I'm using a custom subclass of NSTextView in my project, and I'd like to know if someone knows a way to display graphics in them in the fashion Mail.app from Apple does when showing text being replied to.

Like this:

[image: text is appended a blue vertical line in front of every line]

I read on SO in another message that the component used to display mails might be a WebView. That's fine by me, I could use that. Does that mean then that this line should be drawn using CSS or something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mail's editor *is* a WebView. You could do this with an NSTextView but with a LOT of extra layout and drawing work.

Comment: Ok, great thanks, good to know. So the recommended way would be to do this in the html part of the text I want to display?

Comment: The *easiest* way if you don't need fine control over editing particulars is to use a web view. If you need fine control or rendering options not provided by HTML/CSS, you'll need to do it the  hard way: text system customization via NSTextView and friends.

Comment: Just to be clear: a web view can be placed in editable mode and you can hook high-level editing like insert/delete, etc. to customize within reason. If you need things like custom attributes, you're in for a world of hurt using WebView.

Comment: Yes I saw that already while playing with the editing part of my app. The webview has nice features that allow editing fonts, colors, style, and get the HTML afterwards. Now I need to go learn some css then on how to draw that line on a paragraph, Thanks!

Comment: The CSS you want is border-left: 3px and similar.